# Recalculate prices of units after changing total amount

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel table. Please see screenshot.
Due to the surcharge, my total amount has changed. See cell C12. How to calculate the cost of each unit (column B) so that the amount (C6) will be the same as in cell C12?

**Note. Original prices must be rounded to two decimal places. And in D6 value should be equal to C12.**

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Ratio C12/D6 times each unit price

Comment: Not correct due to rounding. If I use these sums rounded to 2 decimal places, I get 204011.92, not 204009.76.

Comment: You can check this with a calculator.

Comment: Well, in your question you did not mention the necessity to round the unit prices. Will be interesting to see if anybody can come up with an answer that satisfies your needs.

Comment: If you are going to be rounding the prices to two decimals (not mentioned in your original solution), then your Total in `D6` may vary from `C12`.

Comment: Sorry. I've added rounding information to the staging. But it is necessary that D6 and C12 coincide.

Comment: What is the nature of this surcharge? If it is a tax, package, shipping cost or similar, why do you have to "bake" it into the unit prices? It is normal that these kinds of costs are calculated and charged as a separate invoice position.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate like this:

[image]

Left table is called data, cell D8 is called surcharge.
Like that you can calculate the percentage of each product - and based on that get the new amount and from that the new price.

But if you round the new price you will (nearly) never get the same mount as the surcharge ...

Comment: How do online stores do it? When you first collect a basket of goods, then you use bonuses and the amounts of each product are recalculated.

Comment: I don't know .... Maybe the calculate the surcharge per product